# Need full example of using tf-agents Ddpgagent

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, tensorflow-agents

I cannot find any full examples of using the **DdpgAgent** from **tf-agents** in **TensorFlow** and have not been able to get it to work. Could someone please link a full piece of code or a complete tutorial creating and training a **ddpg agent** and a **data_spec** for it.

Comment: Hi, I understand that tutorial might be a great  resource to learn from , however, if you would post what you have tried so far and what is stopping you , I think other users would be much more prone to help you. Also, other developers looking for help with similar issue would greatly benefit from this, should it be resolved :)

Comment: @Proko TBH, (speaking as other developer looking for help with similar issue), a tutorial is what is needed by me, too. SO rules and practices are not always the best course of action.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example in [here](https://github.com/padmaja-kulkarni/TFAgents_examples.git)!. I could recently make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is [one](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/blob/master/tf_agents/agents/ddpg/examples/v2/train_eval.py) in `tf_agents`' Githup repo. It is undocumented, though.

Comment: Also, keras has an [example](https://keras.io/examples/rl/ddpg_pendulum/) in which they implement DDPG from scratch. It's not using `tf-agents`, though, but it does use `Gym` (and keras obviously)

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple code to train ddpg agent of tf-agents, with customized environment on my action/observation data spec. Hope can help. [enter link description here](https://github.com/qaplqq/TFagentDDPGGrid1/blob/main/DDPGa01.ipynb)